# Django custom user with tuple as username

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a solid level on Django, but can't find how to solve this one properly :

I created an API that will be used in multiple mobile projects. So I implemented an Application model that I pass when I log in.

I also created a custom user model :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

username = None
email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
application = models.ForeignKey(Application, null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('email', 'application')
```

I'm using djangorestframework-jwt. So I've an API call that needs an email, password and an Application (apikey as a string FYI) to get a token.

Everything is working fine, except that in this configuration, I'm not able to create another user with the same email but a different Application. Because my EmailField is my USERNAME_FIELD.

Is there any solution that would avoid me to rewrite everything ?

The best thing I have in mind is to add a field (for example a CharField) that would be unique (for example the combinaison of user.id + apikey) that would be filled automatically on creation. But then when I use ./manage.py createsuperuser, django would ask me to fill the field manually. Not a big deal but if you have a better/proper way I'd be glad !

Answer (score 0):

How about use *manytomany* instead of *foreignkey*:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    applications = models.ManyToManyField(Application, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('email', 'application'),)
```

Comment: That's a solution but a user don't have the same permissions between two different applications

Comment: @Cerise It sounds a bit complex. Wish you find out a prefect solution.